# Should I place link in Android title bar?

Tags: gui-design, android

This is more of a design issue/question. In iOS version of application on main Login screen we have all fields for login functionality and we have "About" link in top right on title bar. That is commin/OK for iOS.

We want to have Android app as close as possible, but keep it "Android"-like. How would we implement this "About" functionality? This is no more then just another Activity with some text/trademarks, etc. I can create navigation drawer and dropdown with "About" menu but that will be 2 taps instead of one. What is the way to do this in Android?

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest going with something more recognizable to your users, like embed it in a "hamburger" style sub menu.

Comment: You mean left top drawer menu with "About" option?

Comment: Yea, users have become accustomed to them, plus would allow a quick and easy way to add additional such elements later within it.

Comment: Ok. Within app I'm using same on iOS platform. Here we need only 1 selection hence dilemma.

Comment: If that's the case, and if it were me. I'd put some of that white space below to use and keep their focus on the intended functionality up top by replacing the "About" verbiage with maybe a slide up panel labeled with just a "?" icon or similar fixed to the bottom.

Comment: All I'm seeing here is "about the login page" the hierarchy here is so confusing.

Comment: I think that you don't need an about link in login page. If they want to login, they already know about you...

About what? is the second question. Due to the small limit area; "About company or about product or about us" shortened to "About". About isn't explaining a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In Android items of lesser importance traditionally go under 3-dot menu. I guess, something like this would be appropriate in your case:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 'about' link could be placed bellow the login button. This way the one click access to information is retained without breaking the overall visual theme of android.

This space can be used also to show a few other links e.g. 'terms', 'register' etc. This group of links should be appropriately spaced from the login button so that users don't end up clicking on the login while trying to click on any of the links. But also keep the font size small enough so that they don't steal all the attention.

[image]

Comment: Why is about and terms tied to the login button. Again, all I'm seeing here is terms and about tied to me logging in.